# Getting NSNumber from nsdictionary in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an `NSDictionary` which I created after parsing an XML file. It is storing some numerical value (e.g, 6757677) as a string. Now I want to read it into an `NSNumber`. I have tried following:

```
alert.versionNumber = dictRef["VersionNumber"] as! NSNumber
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1081c9c50) to 'NSNumber' (0x1076abb88).
```

I have also tried following but getting same error:

```
let refID:NSNumber = dictRef["referralID"] as! NSNumber
        alert.refID = refID.integerValue
```

These conversions were simple in Objective C but are giving me a hard time in Swift.

Comment: try getting dictRef["referralID"] as NSString then convert to NSNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var num:NSNumber = NSNumber(integer:(dictRef["referralID"] as! NSString).integerValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `NSString` into a `NSNumber` by taking a detour via a `long long` (the largest signed integer type) or `double` (the largest floating point type). For example:

```
let string : NSString = "42"

// Integer solution:
let intermediate = string.longLongValue
let number = NSNumber(longLong: intermediate)

// Floating point solution:
let intermediate2 = string.doubleValue
let number2 = NSNumber(double: intermediate2)
```

Note that for converting a string to its double value, you might need to use a [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/) to correctly parse the string and handle locale-dependent differences (for example, the decimal separator is a `.` in the US but a `,` in Germany).

Answer (score 0):

```
let dictRef = NSDictionary(objects: ["6757677","1234567"], forKeys: ["VersionNumber", "referralID"])

if let versionNumber = dictRef.valueForKey("VersionNumber")?.integerValue {
    let myNSNumber = NSNumber(integer: versionNumber)
    println(myNSNumber) // 6757677
}
```

Comment: Now try `2147483649` on a 32-bit iOS device ;-) While your solution is correct, I'd recommend to go for `longLongValue` instead.

Comment: That will depend on the OP needs